# Allocation FRONTEND_Tuners on REDHAWK 1.10

Tags: redhawksdr, usrp

I'm using RedHawk 1.10.0 on CentOS 6.5_x64.
I installed UHD 3.7.2.0 in order to try to employ USRP, B100 0r USRP1, both linked by usb connection, on this fantastic framework!
I built new node using GPP and USRP_UHD device and everything seems going well(GPP and USRP_UHD status are STARTED).
Therefore I tried to allocate FrontEnd Tuner from DeviceManager>USRP_UHD>FrontEnd Tuner>Allocate.
After I filled every fields and I pushed Finish.
Every parameter referred to USRP is correct, except for Your Allocation ID in which I have some doubts.
I got this message on my screen:
'The allocation request was not accepted because resources matching all aspects of the request were not available'

and I got this message on the console(level of console debug:TRACE):

```
2014-09-05 17:10:39 TRACE FrontendTunerDevice:369 - CORBA::Boolean frontend::FrontendTunerDevice<TunerStatusStructType>::allocateCapacity(const CF::Properties&) [with TunerStatusStructType = frontend_tuner_status_struct_struct]
2014-09-05 17:10:39 INFO  FrontendTunerDevice:502 - allocateCapacity: NO AVAILABLE TUNER. Make sure that the device has an initialized frontend_tuner_status
2014-09-05 17:10:39 TRACE FrontendTunerDevice:578 - void frontend::FrontendTunerDevice<TunerStatusStructType>::deallocateCapacity(const CF::Properties&) [with TunerStatusStructType = frontend_tuner_status_struct_struct]
2014-09-05 17:10:39 DEBUG FrontendTunerDevice:603 - ALLOCATION_ID NOT FOUND: [dspcola:f096df16-0179-478a-a539-6605a96c17b9]
2014-09-05 17:10:39 DEBUG FrontendTunerDevice:637 - ERROR WHEN DEALLOCATING. SKIPPING...
```

Can some good man help me?

Thanks

Comment: Have you seen / tried the solution posted here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25689591

Comment: Yes, but the problem hasn't still been solved. I implemented that solution and I'm in the same situation of the other user.
Do you have some suggestion? I