# UHD USRP device lacks capacity

Tags: redhawksdr, usrp, software-defined-radio

I'm using Redhawk 1.10.0 on a CentOS 6.5 machine 64 bit and USRP b100 with UHD driver 3.7.2.
The USRP b100 is recognized correctly by the system. It is a USB device. 
I downloaded the latest version of UHD_USRP Device ver. 3.0 for REDHAWK and I created a Node including a GPP and a UHD_USRP devices. 
The Node is started without any problem but when I run a simple waveform to read data from the USRP as a RX_DIGITIZER I got the following error:

```
Failed to create application: usrp_test_248_173059195 Failed to satisfy 'usesdevice' 
dependencies DCE:18964b3d-392e-4b98-a90d-0569b5d46ffefor application 'usrp_test_248_173059195'
IDL:CF/ApplicationFactory/CreateApplicationError:1.0
```

The log of the Device Manager reports that:

```
2014-09-05 17:31:03 TRACE FrontendTunerDevice:369 - CORBA::Boolean frontend::FrontendTunerDevice<TunerStatusStructType>::allocateCapacity(const CF::Properties&) [with TunerStatusStructType = frontend_tuner_status_struct_struct]
2014-09-05 17:31:03 INFO FrontendTunerDevice:502 - allocateCapacity: NO AVAILABLE TUNER. Make sure that the device has an initialized frontend_tuner_status
2014-09-05 17:31:03 TRACE FrontendTunerDevice:578 - void frontend::FrontendTunerDevice<TunerStatusStructType>::deallocateCapacity(const CF::Properties&) [with TunerStatusStructType = frontend_tuner_status_struct_struct]
2014-09-05 17:31:03 DEBUG FrontendTunerDevice:603 - ALLOCATION_ID NOT FOUND: [usrpAllocation]
2014-09-05 17:31:03 DEBUG FrontendTunerDevice:637 - ERROR WHEN DEALLOCATING. SKIPPING...
```

The Node console:

```
2014-09-05 17:31:39 TRACE ApplicationFactory_impl:2132 - Done building Component Info From SPD File
2014-09-05 17:31:39 TRACE ApplicationFactory_impl:1040 - Application has 1 usesdevice dependencies
2014-09-05 17:31:39 TRACE prop_utils:509 - setting struct item FRONTEND::tuner_allocation::allocation_id
2014-09-05 17:31:39 TRACE prop_utils:509 - setting struct item FRONTEND::tuner_allocation::bandwidth
2014-09-05 17:31:39 TRACE prop_utils:509 - setting struct item FRONTEND::tuner_allocation::center_frequency
2014-09-05 17:31:39 TRACE prop_utils:509 - setting struct item FRONTEND::tuner_allocation::group_id
2014-09-05 17:31:39 TRACE prop_utils:509 - setting struct item FRONTEND::tuner_allocation::rf_flow_id
2014-09-05 17:31:39 TRACE prop_utils:509 - setting struct item FRONTEND::tuner_allocation::sample_rate
2014-09-05 17:31:39 TRACE prop_utils:509 - setting struct item FRONTEND::tuner_allocation::tuner_type
2014-09-05 17:31:39 TRACE AllocationManager_impl:134 - Servicing 1 allocation request(s)
2014-09-05 17:31:39 TRACE AllocationManager_impl:144 - Allocation request DCE:18964b3d-392e-4b98-a90d-0569b5d46ffe contains 3 properties
2014-09-05 17:31:39 TRACE AllocationManager_impl:243 - Allocating against device uhd_node:USRP_UHD_1
2014-09-05 17:31:39 TRACE AllocationManager_impl:353 - Matching DCE:cdc5ee18-7ceb-4ae6-bf4c-31f983179b4d 'FRONTEND::TUNER' eq 'FRONTEND::TUNER'
2014-09-05 17:31:39 TRACE AllocationManager_impl:353 - Matching DCE:0f99b2e4-9903-4631-9846-ff349d18ecfb 'USRP' eq 'USRP'
2014-09-05 17:31:39 TRACE AllocationManager_impl:395 - Adding external property FRONTEND::tuner_allocation
2014-09-05 17:31:39 TRACE AllocationManager_impl:407 - Matched 2 properties
2014-09-05 17:31:39 TRACE AllocationManager_impl:264 - Allocating 1 properties (1 calls)
2014-09-05 17:31:39 TRACE AllocationManager_impl:267 - Device lacks sufficient capacity
2014-09-05 17:31:39 TRACE AllocationManager_impl:243 - Allocating against device uhd_node:GPP_1
2014-09-05 17:31:39 TRACE AllocationManager_impl:353 - Matching DCE:cdc5ee18-7ceb-4ae6-bf4c-31f983179b4d 'GPP' eq 'FRONTEND::TUNER'
2014-09-05 17:31:39 TRACE AllocationManager_impl:248 - Matching failed
2014-09-05 17:31:39 DEBUG ApplicationFactory_impl:1060 - Failed to satisfy 'usesdevice' dependencies DCE:18964b3d-392e-4b98-a90d-0569b5d46ffefor application 'usrp_test_248_173059195'
2014-09-05 17:31:39 TRACE ApplicationFactory_impl:528 - Unbinding the naming context
2014-09-05 17:31:39 TRACE Properties:85 - Destruction for properties
2014-09-05 17:31:39 TRACE PRF:312 - Deleting PRF containing 4 properties
```

I used the following parameters:

```
<usesdevicedependencies>
<usesdevice id="DCE:18964b3d-392e-4b98-a90d-0569b5d46ffe"
type="usesUSRP">
<propertyref refid="DCE:cdc5ee18-7ceb-4ae6-bf4c-31f983179b4d"
value="FRONTEND::TUNER" />
<propertyref refid="DCE:0f99b2e4-9903-4631-9846-ff349d18ecfb"
value="USRP" />
<structref refid="FRONTEND::tuner_allocation">
<simpleref refid="FRONTEND::tuner_allocation::tuner_type"
value="RX_DIGITIZER" />
<simpleref refid="FRONTEND::tuner_allocation::allocation_id"
value="usrpAllocation" />
<simpleref refid="FRONTEND::tuner_allocation::center_frequency"
value="102500000" />
<simpleref refid="FRONTEND::tuner_allocation::bandwidth"
value="320000" />
<simpleref refid="FRONTEND::tuner_allocation::sample_rate"
value="250000" />
<simpleref refid="FRONTEND::tuner_allocation::group_id"
value="" />
<simpleref refid="FRONTEND::tuner_allocation::rf_flow_id"
value="" />
</structref>
</usesdevice>
</usesdevicedependencies>
```

The b100 configuration is the following:

```
-- USRP-B100 clock control: 10
--   r_counter: 2
--   a_counter: 0
--   b_counter: 20
--   prescaler: 8
--   vco_divider: 5
--   chan_divider: 5
--   vco_rate: 1600.000000MHz
--   chan_rate: 320.000000MHz
--   out_rate: 64.000000MHz
-- 
  _____________________________________________________
 /
|       Device: B-Series Device
|     _____________________________________________________
|    /
|   |       Mboard: B100
|   |   revision: 8192
|   |   serial: E5R10Z1B1
|   |   FW Version: 4.0
|   |   FPGA Version: 11.4
|   |   
|   |   Time sources: none, external, _external_
|   |   Clock sources: internal, external, auto
|   |   Sensors: ref_locked
|   |     _____________________________________________________
|   |    /
|   |   |       RX DSP: 0
|   |   |   Freq range: -32.000 to 32.000 Mhz
|   |     _____________________________________________________
|   |    /
|   |   |       RX Dboard: A
|   |   |   ID: WBX v3, WBX v3 + Simple GDB (0x0057)
|   |   |   Serial: E5R1BW6XW
|   |   |     _____________________________________________________
|   |   |    /
|   |   |   |       RX Frontend: 0
|   |   |   |   Name: WBXv3 RX+GDB
|   |   |   |   Antennas: TX/RX, RX2, CAL
|   |   |   |   Sensors: lo_locked
|   |   |   |   Freq range: 68.750 to 2200.000 Mhz
|   |   |   |   Gain range PGA0: 0.0 to 31.5 step 0.5 dB
|   |   |   |   Connection Type: IQ
|   |   |   |   Uses LO offset: No
|   |   |     _____________________________________________________
|   |   |    /
|   |   |   |       RX Codec: A
|   |   |   |   Name: ad9522
|   |   |   |   Gain range pga: 0.0 to 20.0 step 1.0 dB
|   |     _____________________________________________________
|   |    /
|   |   |       TX DSP: 0
|   |   |   Freq range: -32.000 to 32.000 Mhz
|   |     _____________________________________________________
|   |    /
|   |   |       TX Dboard: A
|   |   |   ID: WBX v3 (0x0056)
|   |   |   Serial: E5R1BW6XW
|   |   |     _____________________________________________________
|   |   |    /
|   |   |   |       TX Frontend: 0
|   |   |   |   Name: WBXv3 TX+GDB
|   |   |   |   Antennas: TX/RX, CAL
|   |   |   |   Sensors: lo_locked
|   |   |   |   Freq range: 68.750 to 2200.000 Mhz
|   |   |   |   Gain range PGA0: 0.0 to 31.0 step 1.0 dB
|   |   |   |   Connection Type: IQ
|   |   |   |   Uses LO offset: No
|   |   |     _____________________________________________________
|   |   |    /
|   |   |   |       TX Codec: A
|   |   |   |   Name: ad9522
|   |   |   |   Gain range pga: -20.0 to 0.0 step 0.1 dB
```

Where's my fault?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *frontend_tuner_status* struct sequence is what defines the device capabilities and capacity. If the sequence is empty, the allocation will always result in lack of capacity. An empty *frontend_tuner_status* property is usually the result of not specifying the target device, or not being able to find the specified target device.

You must specify the target device using the *target_device* struct property. This can be done within the Node or at run-time. Previous versions of the USRP_UHD REDHAWK Device only allowed the IP address to be specified using a property, but in order to support USB-connected (and in general, non-network-connected) USRP devices, this has been replaced with the *target_device* struct property.

The *target_device* property allows the user to specify *ip_address*, *name*, *serial*, or *type*, and will use the first USRP hardware device that meets the criteria, if one is found. The information that should be specified in the *target_device* struct can be determined by setting the *update_available_devices* property to true, causing the *available_devices* struct sequence to be populated with all found devices (the same devices and information that is reported by the command line tool `uhd_find_devices`).

To determine if the USRP_UHD REDHAWK Device is connected to a target device, inspect the properties. Specifically, *frontend_tuner_status* sequence will be empty if not linked to a hardware device, as well as the *device_motherboards* and *device_channels* properties.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
In fact the struct was empty. I set the type to b100 but I immediately got the following error: 
`Error while executing callable. Caused by org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: 
Error while executing callable. Caused by org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE:`

Is it a bug of USRP_UHD?

Comment: The error likely indicates that the USRP_UHD Device terminated due to an unhandled exception. Is there additional information in the log files? You may have to set the debug level to DEBUG or TRACE to identify where in the USRP_UHD code the exception is being thrown.

Comment: The B100 device is discontinued and not available for testing, so the behavior is unknown. Testing with a B210 device has been successful, however. Initial testing with the B210 had similar results to what you are seeing, and it ended up being a UHD call that worked for other USRP device types threw an exception for the B210. Something similar is likely happening with the B100.

Comment: I added some prints in the code, like "here" or "there", to monitor where the fault occurs. But this time it didn't occur anytime! Could it be an error due to temporization or a race conditions? If it occurs again I'll report the log. Anyway the allocation is not good at all, since I'm allowed to allocate only a 40MHz bandwidth, no more, no less, and for sure it is a wrong value for USRP b100.

Comment: I tried with USRP b200 as you suggested and the behaviour is not amazing. It allows me to allocate a bandwidth of 56 MHz (the maximum value accepted). Interestingly, the FFT plot of the allocation port does not make any sense because the frequency axes is in mHz (E-3) and no signals are visible. Did I miss something? Any suggestion?

Comment: Bandwidth range (of exactly 40 MHz in your case) is queried from the device itself, as are the frequency, sample rate, and gain ranges. The output of `uhd_usrp_probe` that you posted shows that you are using the WBX daughtercard, which according to [Ettus](http://www.ettus.com/kb/detail/usrp-bandwidth) has a 40 MHz bandwidth. This is the analog filter bandwidth, but the effective bandwidth is dependent on the sample rate chosen (as the link provided explains). It is more meaningful to set the sample rate when using a USRP.

Comment: I believe my initial response resolved your initial question and you have asked two new questions in your recent comments. Please select my response as correct if you agree so that it will assist others. Let's move your additional questions to new posts and I will respond there, rather than burying this information in the comments.

Comment: I will open a new post, but the problem has been solved in an unusual way.